# I need to send id using select in html

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, forms

I want to show name of the record in select, but I need to send only id of that record.

**My code:**

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => 'ZanrController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) }}

       <div>
            <label class="form-label">
               <b> <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Žánr *</a></b>
            </label>
            <div>
                <select name="druh" class="form-control">
                    <?php
                        $res = mysqli_query($link, "select * from druh_lit_zanrus");
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                        {
                    ?>
                       <option> <?php echo $row["id_druhu_lit_zanru"]; ?></option>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

    {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Please highlight what exactly you want to submit. Also the very point of Laravel blade is to separate the logic and views, you should refactor your code.

Comment: As per my understanding  you would like to send dropdown selected value on submit.```<option value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"> <?php echo $row["id_druhu_lit_zanru"]; ?></option>```. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I need to send to database the id of selected value: id_druhu_lit_zanru, but I need to show name of that record. You know- show name but send id

Comment: Ok. So you can pass id in value and name in option like this - ```<option value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"> <?php echo $row["name"]; ?></option> ```

Comment: Welcome. I would be appreciate if you accept my below edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send selected value in option

```
<option value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"> <?php echo $row["name"]; ?></option>
```